# Modify regular expression to match pec

Tags: regex

i have a database with a lot of emails and a regular expression that match all of them.
The regex is

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

I neet to modify it in order to match only addresses that contain words pec in the last part of address.
For example:

asd.qwe@pec.it should match
dav@asd.it should not match

Thank you very much

Comment: *I need to modify it*. So go ahead and modify it. Seriously, have you made any effort to do anything yourself? This isn't a code or regular expression writing service.

Comment: no comment.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing everything after the `@` with:

```
(?:\w*.?pec(?:.?\w+)*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/2owrLg/1